# How can i make the rendering process faster in JAVA?

Tags: java, graphics, render

I am making a software that has a screen filtering process. The code can already shift the colors and apply it to the frame the only problem is that It takes around 40-50 seconds for the filtered window to render. Is there any way I can make it faster? I would also like to ask which part of the code makes the process longer and time consuming. I will really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Here is my code.

```
 public RedGreenFilter(int k1, int k2, int k3) {
        this.k1 = k1;
        this.k2 = k2;
        this.k3 = k3;
 }

    @Override
    public BufferedImage filter(final BufferedImage src, BufferedImage dst) {
        if (dst == null) {
            dst = this.createCompatibleDestImage(src, null);
        }

        // make sure the two images have the same size, color space, etc.
        // MISSING !!! ???

        DataBufferInt inBuffer = (DataBufferInt) src.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
        DataBufferInt outBuffer = (DataBufferInt) dst.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
        int[] inData = inBuffer.getData();
        int[] outData = outBuffer.getData();



        int simR = 0, simG = 0, simB = 0, mild = 10, moderate = 20, strong = 40;
        float cIndex = MyDeficiency.cIndex;
        float angle = MyDeficiency.angle;
        float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

        int prevIn = 0;
        int prevOut = 0;
        final int length = inData.length;

        int corrG;
        int corrR;
        int corrB;

        int SizeOfScreen = src.getHeight() * src.getWidth();



        final int[] redArray = new int[SizeOfScreen];
        final int[] blueArray = new int[SizeOfScreen];
        final int[] greenArray = new int[SizeOfScreen];



        for (int i = 0; i < SizeOfScreen; i++) {
            final int in = inData[i];
            if (in == prevIn) {
                outData[i] = prevOut;
            } else {

                final int r = (0xff0000 & in) >> 16;
                final int g = (0xff00 & in) >> 8;
                final int b = 0xff & in;

                // get linear rgb values in the range 0..2^15-1
                final int r_lin = rgb2lin_red_LUT[r];
                final int g_lin = rgb2lin_red_LUT[g];
                final int b_lin = rgb2lin_red_LUT[b];

               //http://publication.gunadarma.ac.id/bitstream/123456789/12232/1/Slide_Mahendra_54411250.pdf 
               float L = (17.8824f * r + 43.5161f * g + 4.11935f * b);
               float M = (3.4565f * r + 27.1554f * g + 3.86714f * b);
               float S = (0.02996f * r + 0.18431f * g + 1.46709f * b); 

               float dL = ( 0 * L + 2.02344f * M - 2.52581f * S);
               float dM = ( 0 * L + 1 * M + 0 * S);
               float dS = ( 0 * L + 0 * M + 1 * S);

               float pL = ( 1 * L + 0 * M + 0 * S);
               float pM = ( 0.494207f * L + 0 * M + 1.24827f * S);
               float pS = ( 0 * L + 0 * M + 1 * S);    

                // simulated red and green are identical
                // scale the matrix values to 0..2^15 for integer computations 
                // of the simulated protan values.
                // divide after the computation by 2^15 to rescale.
                // also divide by 2^15 asnd multiply by 2^8 to scale the linear rgb to 0..255
                // total division is by 2^15 * 2^15 / 2^8 = 2^22
                // shift the bits by 22 places instead of dividing
                int r_blind = (int) (k1 * r_lin + k2 * g_lin) >> 22;
                int b_blind = (int) (k3 * r_lin - k3 * g_lin + 32768 * b_lin) >> 22;

                if (r_blind < 0) {
                    r_blind = 0;
                } else if (r_blind > 255) {
                    r_blind = 255;
                }

                if (b_blind < 0) {
                    b_blind = 0;
                } else if (b_blind > 255) {
                    b_blind = 255;
                }

                // convert reduced linear rgb to gamma corrected rgb
                int red = lin2rgb_LUT[r_blind];
                red = red >= 0 ? red : 256 + red; // from unsigned to signed
                int blue = lin2rgb_LUT[b_blind];
                blue = blue >= 0 ? blue : 256 + blue;   // from unsigned to signed

               if(k1 == 9591 && k2 == 23173){
                   x = dL;
                   y = dM;
                   z = dS;
               }

               if(k1 == 3683 && k2 == 29084){
                   x = pL;
                   y = pM;
                   z = pS;
               }

               //SEVERITY

               //PROTAN
               //normal to mild
               if (angle > 0.70 && cIndex < 1.2){
                    simR = (int)(0.0809533970341018f * x -0.1305188419612954f * y + 0.11673398252989027f * z);
                    simG = (int)(-0.01025222049871863f * x + 0.054025275314902886f * y -0.11362003603724172f * z);
                    simB = (int)(-0.0003651971010795924f * x -0.004121801653701777f * y + 0.693511617368688f * z);
                }
               //mild to moderate
               else if (angle > 0.70 && cIndex < 3 && cIndex > 1.20){
                    simR = (int)(0.0809533970341018f * x -0.1305188419612954f * y + 0.11673398252989027f * z) + mild;
                    simG = (int)(-0.01025222049871863f * x + 0.054025275314902886f * y -0.11362003603724172f * z);
                    simB = (int)(-0.0003651971010795924f * x -0.004121801653701777f * y + 0.693511617368688f * z);
                }

               //moderate to strong
               else if (angle > 0.70 && cIndex < 4 && cIndex > 3){
                    simR = (int)(0.0809533970341018f * x -0.1305188419612954f * y + 0.11673398252989027f * z) + moderate;
                    simG = (int)(-0.01025222049871863f * x + 0.054025275314902886f * y -0.11362003603724172f * z);
                    simB = (int)(-0.0003651971010795924f * x -0.004121801653701777f * y + 0.693511617368688f * z); 
                }

               //strong to super strong
               else if (angle > 0.70 && cIndex > 4){
                    simR = (int)(0.0809533970341018f * x -0.1305188419612954f * y + 0.11673398252989027f * z) + strong;
                    simG = (int)(-0.01025222049871863f * x + 0.054025275314902886f * y -0.11362003603724172f * z);
                    simB = (int)(-0.0003651971010795924f * x -0.004121801653701777f * y + 0.693511617368688f * z); 
                }

               //DEUTAN
               //normal to mild
               if (angle < 0.70 && angle > -65.00 && cIndex < 1.2){
                    simR = (int)(0.0809533970341018f * x -0.1305188419612954f * y + 0.11673398252989027f * z);
                    simG = (int)(-0.01025222049871863f * x + 0.054025275314902886f * y -0.11362003603724172f * z);
                    simB = (int)(-0.0003651971010795924f * x -0.004121801653701777f * y + 0.693511617368688f * z);
                }
               //mild to moderate
               else if (angle < 0.70 && angle > -65.00 && cIndex < 3 && cIndex > 1.20){
                    simR = (int)(0.0809533970341018f * x -0.1305188419612954f * y + 0.11673398252989027f * z);
                    simG = (int)(-0.01025222049871863f * x + 0.054025275314902886f * y -0.11362003603724172f * z) + mild;
                    simB = (int)(-0.0003651971010795924f * x -0.004121801653701777f * y + 0.693511617368688f * z);
                }

               //moderate to strong
               else if (angle < 0.70 && angle > -65 && cIndex < 4 && cIndex > 3){
                    simR = (int)(0.0809533970341018f * x -0.1305188419612954f * y + 0.11673398252989027f * z);
                    simG = (int)(-0.01025222049871863f * x + 0.054025275314902886f * y -0.11362003603724172f * z) + moderate;
                    simB = (int)(-0.0003651971010795924f * x -0.004121801653701777f * y + 0.693511617368688f * z) ; 
                }

               //strong to super strong
               else if (angle < 0.7 && angle > -65 && cIndex > 4){
                    simR = (int)(0.0809533970341018f * x -0.1305188419612954f * y + 0.11673398252989027f * z);
                    simG = (int)(-0.01025222049871863f * x + 0.054025275314902886f * y -0.11362003603724172f * z) + strong;
                    simB = (int)(-0.0003651971010795924f * x -0.004121801653701777f * y + 0.693511617368688f * z) ; 
                }

                int errR = r - simR;
                int errG = g - simG;      
                int errB = b - simB;

                float errModR = (0 * errR + 0 * errG + 0 * errB);
                float errModG = (0.7f * errR + 1 * errG + 0 * errB);
                float errModB = (0.7f * errR + 0 * errG + 1 * errB);


                corrR = (int) errModR + r;
                corrG = (int) errModG + g;
                corrB = (int) errModB + b;

                /*
                int corrR = 0;
                int corrG = 0;
                int corrB = 0;
                */
                //MyDeficiency my = new MyDeficiency();

                if(r == 255 && g == 255 && b == 255){
                    corrR = corrG = corrB = 255;
                }
                if(r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 0){
                    corrR = corrG = corrB = 0;
                }


                final int out = 0xff000000 | (corrR << 16) | (corrG << 8) | corrB ;

                redArray[i] = (out >> 16) & 0xFF;
                greenArray[i] = (out >> 8) & 0xFF;
                blueArray[i] = (out >> 0) & 0xFF; 

                //System.out.println("r: " +" " + redArray[i]+  " "+ " g:" +" " +greenArray[i] +" " +"b:"+" "+ blueArray[i] + " " +"i:"+ " "+i);

                //System.out.println("sR: " + (red << 16) + "sG: " +(red <<8)+ " sB: " + blue);




               //outData[i] = out;
                //prevIn = in;
               //prevOut = out;


            }
        }
            //System.out.println(SizeOfScreen);


        Window w = new Window(null);
        w.add(new JComponent() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                int alpha = 190; // 50% transparent
                int pixelcounter = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < src.getHeight(); i++){
                   for(int j = 0; j < src.getWidth(); j++){
                        Color myColour = new Color(redArray[pixelcounter],greenArray[pixelcounter],blueArray[pixelcounter], alpha);
                        g.setColor(myColour);
                        g.fillRect(j,i,1,1);
                        pixelcounter++;
                    }

                }

            }

            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight());
            }
            });
            w.pack();
            w.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            w.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

/**
* This sets the background of the window to be transparent.
*/
            AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(w, false);
            setTransparent(w);

            w.setVisible(true); 

            //w.setVisible(false);


        return dst;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is not an acronym.

Comment: HAHAHA well i already know that just emphasizing that my code is in Java haha

Comment: Man you're creating a new Window and a new JComponent every time you call the filter function... are you really surprised it is slow? :)

Comment: If the code works, but is slow, perhaps try [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: @Oneiros do you have a suggestion? I also think its the problem but i dont know how to call it if i made a method. The graphics g I'm not sure on how to pass parameters to it.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code?

Comment: @naomiyx I think you need to study some OOP and learn how to create classes, instances, fields etc. You can't just throw all your code in one single method, it is hard to read, hard to mantain and really really slow. You should create just one window and swap its content on each refresh